# How to create a multipart post request to upload a file to server using webclient?

Tags: c#, webclient, multipartform-data, webclient.uploaddata

I want to implement functionality to upload files to box.And it requires a multipart post request.I am using .net 3.5, so I can't use HttpClient. Also, I want to implement it using webclient as it allows to track progress and I want to show the progress in the UI. I have to send `{"name":"tigers.jpeg", "parent":{"id":"xxxxx"}}` as parameter along with the file to be uploaded.How do I create such a request, which also allows me to track progress.

Comment: You must use an HttpWebRequest to make complex POST's, you can track the progress just by yourself as you're the one who will send the content's data.

Comment: But how do I send a Multipart request from HttpWebRequest.

Comment: You need to create an stream, add the appropiate headers and write the data to the stream, take a look at this: http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c